In react native view-shot package not supporting style properties for large screenshot
enter image description here
In the react-native-view-shot package, style properties are not being applied correctly for large screenshots. Specifically, when a border radius value other than 0 is used, the styles are not reflected in the screenshot.
 <ShareModal
                  currentDataOnPress={currentDataOnPress}
                  shareScreenParams={shareScreenParams}
                  dataFileOnPress={dataFileOnPress}
                  isVisible={isModalVisible}
                  onClose={() => {
                    handleShareData && handleShareData(false);
                    setModalVisible(false);
                  }}
                  deviceDataScreenRef={deviceDataScreenRef}
                  handleShareData={handleShareData}
                />

     const handleShareScreenshot = async () => {
            try {
              if (deviceDataScreenRef) {
                const uri = await captureRef(deviceDataScreenRef, {
                  fileName: `data-screenshot-${DateTime.formatDateTime(new Date())}`,
                  format: "jpg",
                  quality: 0.8,
                  snapshotContentContainer : true 
                });
        
                if (uri) {
                  await Sharing.shareAsync(uri);
                }
                onClose();
              }
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          };


Can you add more info: Screenshot of your app and result of using react-native-view-shot

i added image, can you please check with this above link enter image description here

Still i am facing this border radius issue how can i fix this
if its small data able to get correctly  else it should be too large not able to get styles at end of the data snap
